# iPhone App and FTP working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ftp

How to upload any image on FTP server in xcode for any iPhone app ?
I have FTP account details so please tell any way as i am new to iOS platform.

I have referred :

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFFTPStreamRef/Reference/reference.html

but not getting properly.

Comment: Did you see this?  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html

Comment: Hi borrrden,

I have seen it.. But it's pretty complex to understand.
I want to upload local image file of our xcode hierarchy on FTP server on button click.
So please help me out.

Comment: Networking in general is complex to understand.  Nothing you can do about it.  Try using a library to help you (like the one in the answer)

Comment: Was this helpful? Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library (for **iPhone** and Mac OS X) that makes provides easy to implement communications with a FTP server very straightforward: [SCRFTPRequest](https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest)

Attached you can find an [example](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19438780/FTPtest.zip)  (simple upload)

Comment: Hi TonyMkenu,

It's a Mac64BitApp..
I want it in iPhone app...

So what can i do ?

Comment: So... it's not easy to implement?